# how to convert db result row to nested json format

Tags: json

I have this json response from db.

```
    {"StudentId":"1","SubjectId":"1","Mark":"61"}{"StudentId":"1","SubjectId":"2","Mark":"75"}{"StudentId":"1","SubjectId":"3","Mark":"87"}{"StudentId":"2","SubjectId":"1","Mark":"82"}{"StudentId":"2","SubjectId":"2","Mark":"64"}{"StudentId":"2","SubjectId":"3","Mark":"77"}
```

I want convert as

```
{"StudentId":"1",
    "Mark":[ "1":"61", "2":"75", "3":"87" ]
}
{"StudentId":"2",
    "Mark":[ "1":"82", "2":"64", "3":"77" ]
}
```

By using this I want to generate a html table.

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance using Couchbase? This transformation would be quite easy in N1QL. Here's the query:

```
SELECT data.StudentId, OBJECT v.SubjectId:v.Mark FOR v IN ARRAY_AGG(data) END as Mark
FROM [{"StudentId":"1","SubjectId":"1","Mark":"61"}, 
      {"StudentId":"1","SubjectId":"2","Mark":"75"}, 
      {"StudentId":"1","SubjectId":"3","Mark":"87"}, 
      {"StudentId":"2","SubjectId":"1","Mark":"82"}, 
      {"StudentId":"2","SubjectId":"2","Mark":"64"}, 
      {"StudentId":"2","SubjectId":"3","Mark":"77"}] data
GROUP BY data.StudentId
```

Presumably you would be replacing the hard-coded array in the FROM clause with a query to get the data in the first place.

Here's the output:

```
[
  {
    "Mark": {
      "1": "61",
      "2": "75",
      "3": "87"
    },
    "StudentId": "1"
  },
  {
    "Mark": {
      "1": "82",
      "2": "64",
      "3": "77"
    },
    "StudentId": "2"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I am not using N1QL. I am using MySQL. Its my PHP project.

Answer (score 0):

```
{"StudentId":"1","SubjectId":"1","Mark":"61"}, 
{"StudentId":"1","SubjectId":"2","Mark":"75"}, 
{"StudentId":"1","SubjectId":"3","Mark":"87"}, 
{"StudentId":"2","SubjectId":"1","Mark":"82"}, 
{"StudentId":"2","SubjectId":"2","Mark":"64"}, 
{"StudentId":"2","SubjectId":"3","Mark":"77"}
```

In DB I have results table with attributes StudentId, SubjectId, Mark
I fetched the data and converted to JSON. 
I finally want data in this format.

```
[
  {
    "Mark": {
      "1": "61",
      "2": "75",
      "3": "87"
    },
    "StudentId": "1"
  },
  {
    "Mark": {
      "1": "82",
      "2": "64",
      "3": "77"
    },
    "StudentId": "2"
  }
]
```